# Bing, Yahoo more result on single page using url

Tags: search-engine, yahoo, bing, yahoo-search

**How can i fetch more result from bing and yahoo search engine. (Using url)**

For Google we pass "num" parameter, i.e - https://www.google.com/#num=30&q=test (give 30 res)

So what are parameter to pass for bing and yahoo to get more result.

**Anyone had idea?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting more search results per page via URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660910/getting-more-search-results-per-page-via-url)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it!

To get 30 result on single page, pass below parameter,

For google use num=30 -  https://www.google.com/search?q=test&num=30

For bing use count=30 -  http://www.bing.com/search?q=test&count=30

For yahoo use n=30 -  https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=test&n=30

Comment: Answer is old, so some links might not give required result

Comment: everything seems to be still up to date